# Multiple Channel Import Shared Fields

Tags: channel, import

Using a basic example. If i want to import - 
Pages channel &
News channel

And they both use SEO Title, SEO Desc fields. When importing the second zip, it errors out and needs the fields renaming. Which defeats the purpose.

Is this just not a currently available feature?

Answer (score 0):

Currently - i manually combined the files in the field folder. And then modified the JSON file to do what i wanted.

It works, just cumbersome!